# Why is my bash history not sorted by date?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

My mac bash history looks like this (I'm copying just the last +100 lines):

```
 2769  23/09/14 17:54:09nano ~/.bash_profile
 2770  23/09/14 17:54:21nano ~/.bash_profile
 2771  23/09/14 17:54:28source ~/.bash_profile
 2772  23/09/14 17:54:32ngrok 3000
 2773  24/09/14 14:07:38ngrok 0.0.0.0:3000
 2774  25/09/14 09:00:41ngrok 0.0.0.0:3000
 2775  17/10/14 16:03:11cd Down*/sample_app*
 2776  17/10/14 16:03:53rails server -p 3667
 2777  17/10/14 16:03:59bundle install
 2778  17/10/14 16:12:28rails server -p 3667
 2779  17/10/14 16:13:06bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
 2780  17/10/14 16:13:15rails server -p 3667
 2781  17/10/14 16:17:33rails server -p 3667
 2782  17/10/14 16:19:45rails server -p 3667
 2783  17/10/14 16:20:24rails server -p 3667
 2784  17/10/14 16:21:22rails server -p 3667
 2785  17/10/14 16:22:04rails server -p 3667
 2786  17/10/14 16:26:50rails server -p 3667
 2787  17/10/14 16:30:42rails server -p 3667
 2788  25/09/14 09:03:31curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/twilio/voice -d 'foo=bar'
 2789  25/09/14 16:11:35curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2790  25/09/14 16:13:29curl
 2791  25/09/14 16:13:35curl --help
 2792  25/09/14 16:34:48curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2793  25/09/14 16:35:22curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2794  25/09/14 16:38:25curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2795  25/09/14 16:38:49curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2796  25/09/14 16:39:33curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/twilio/voice -d 'foo=bar'
 2797  25/09/14 16:40:57curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2798  25/09/14 16:47:28curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2799  25/09/14 17:55:23curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2800  25/09/14 17:56:17curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2801  25/09/14 17:56:54curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send
 2802  25/09/14 17:57:28curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send
 2803  25/09/14 17:57:42curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'foo=bar'
 2804  25/09/14 17:59:39curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'number_to_send_to = +4479311'
 2805  25/09/14 18:00:41curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'number_to_send_to=+4479311'
 2806  25/09/14 18:13:39curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/sms/send -d 'number_to_send_to=+4479311'
 2807  20/12/14 23:06:21git status
 2808  20/12/14 23:07:19git add config/routes.rb
 2809  20/12/14 23:07:29git add app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
 2810  20/12/14 23:07:51git commit -m "accommodating a login screen"
 2811  20/12/14 23:08:01git add app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
 2812  20/12/14 23:08:20git commit -m "These changes allowed to fix the layout of the login screen"
 2813  21/12/14 10:24:53history
```

Why is it not sorted according to date? I am usually using several terminal windows at once - is this the reason? How can I display the history in chronological order?

I tried the suggestion by Arvid by it did not work. Here is the output:

```
 2445  28/09/14 21:33:21rails server
 2446  29/09/14 11:43:43rails server
 2447  29/09/14 11:44:38rails server
 1981  30/07/14 22:16:37vagrant
 2195  30/10/14 15:17:46/Users/nnikolo/Downloads/bipolar-master/pkg/osx/install.command ; exit;
 2196  30/10/14 15:19:13cd Downl*/bipol*
 2197  30/10/14 15:19:34cd pkg/osx
 2198  30/10/14 15:19:37ls -all
 2199  30/10/14 15:19:48./build.sh
 2200  30/10/14 15:20:14cd ..
 2201  30/10/14 15:20:19cd ..
 2202  30/10/14 15:20:30cd hook/qt
 2203  30/10/14 15:20:34ls -all
 2204  30/10/14 15:21:05./build.sh
 2205  30/10/14 15:27:32ls -all
 2206  30/10/14 15:27:38pwd
 2207  30/10/14 15:27:41cd ..
 2208  30/10/14 15:27:42cd ..
 2209  30/10/14 15:27:46ls -all
 2210  30/10/14 15:27:50cd pkg/osx
 2211  30/10/14 15:27:53ls -all
 2212  30/10/14 15:28:01./build.sh
 2213  30/10/14 15:28:22cd ../..
 2214  30/10/14 15:28:26ls -all
 2215  30/10/14 15:28:30cd hook
 2216  30/10/14 15:28:32ls -all
 2217  30/10/14 15:28:35cd at
 2218  30/10/14 15:28:38cd qt
 2219  30/10/14 15:28:41ls -all
 2220  30/10/14 15:28:55ls -all qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1
 2221  30/10/14 15:31:04cd ..
 2222  30/10/14 15:31:09ls -akk
 2223  30/10/14 15:31:11cd qt
 2224  30/10/14 15:31:13ls -all
 2225  30/10/14 15:31:27build
 2226  30/10/14 15:31:31./build
 2227  30/10/14 15:31:39./build.sh
 2228  30/10/14 15:36:48ls -all
 2229  30/10/14 15:36:56./install.sh
 2230  30/10/14 15:37:05cd ..
 2231  30/10/14 15:37:06cd ..
 2232  30/10/14 15:37:10ls -all
 2233  30/10/14 15:37:17cd pkg/osx
 2234  30/10/14 15:37:21ls -all
 2235  30/10/14 15:37:29./build.sh
 2236  30/10/14 15:37:49nano build.sh
 2237  30/10/14 15:38:14gedit build.sh
 2238  30/10/14 15:40:42sudo nano build.sh
 2239  30/10/14 15:40:59./build.sh
 2240  30/10/14 16:01:55./build.sh
 2241  30/10/14 16:07:13ls -all
 2242  30/10/14 16:07:23./install.command
 2243  30/10/14 16:07:46pwd
 2244  30/10/14 16:07:50ls -all ../..
 2245  30/10/14 16:08:07ls -all ../../hook/
 2246  30/10/14 16:08:09ls -all ../../hook/qt/
 2247  30/10/14 16:08:49nano ../../hook/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.patch
 2248  30/10/14 16:09:43cd ../../hook/qt/
 2249  30/10/14 16:09:45ls -all
 2250  30/10/14 16:09:59nano build
 2251  30/10/14 16:10:12ls -all build/*
 2252  30/10/14 16:10:26cd build/*
 2253  30/10/14 16:10:28cd build
 2254  30/10/14 16:10:36qmake
 2255  30/10/14 16:10:39./qmake
 2256  30/10/14 16:10:49make
 2089  31/08/14 14:32:51пвд
 2090  31/08/14 14:32:57pwd
 2091  31/08/14 14:33:02git status
 2092  31/08/14 14:33:13git add edgeR-de.r.history
 2093  31/08/14 14:33:24git commit -m "Interim save"
 2094  31/08/14 14:33:42history | grep remote
 2095  31/08/14 14:33:59history | grep push
 2096  31/08/14 14:34:05git push origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your multiple terminals is the reason. The bash history is written when you exit the shell, not individually for each command.

You can get your history file in chronological order with sort:

```
history | sort -k2
```

If your want your history file to be written more continoulsy, I believe [this blog post explains it quite well](http://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command/)

I also found [this unix stack exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately this did not work.